# MIPS jump instruction and consequence of the absolute value

Tags: assembly, mips32, machine-code

Suppose we have a jump instruction at address 0x20000004. Now, as I know it, the jump interval is NOT relative to the PC value but it is an absolute interval of about 1/16 of a 32 bit register max value. Now, considering how the jump instruction is constructed in machine code, would it mean that the maximum backward jump -in this particular case- is of 1 instructions, or to address 0x20000000? Or in the opposite case: jump instruction at address 0x1FFFFFFC and I want to jump ahead of 2 instructions to address 0x20000004. Is it not doable? How does the assembler manage to not place instructions in one of those 2 cases?
Edit: fixed some errors

Comment: _"would it mean that the maximum backward jump -in this particular case- is of 4 instructions"_ What? Where did you get that idea?  _"or to address 0x20000000?"_ Each instruction is 4 bytes, not 1 byte. _"jump instruction at address 0x1FFFFFFE"_ It cannot be, since instructions must be word-aligned.

Comment: Normally it's the linker that's placing sections, and these are big enough ranges so you usually have no problem fitting all your code (at least your module) into a single one. Incidentally GNU `ld` seems buggy, it just truncates the jump without even a warning if you force this scenario to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The lower 28 bits of the target address are set to the 26 least significant bits of the `J` instruction word, shifted 2 bits to the left.
- The upper 4 bits of the target address are set to the 4 most significant bits of the address of the instruction in the branch delay slot.

So you can jump anywhere within the same 256 MB region as the instruction in the branch delay slot (with word granularity). In practice this is the same as being able to jump anywhere within the same 256 MB region as the `J` instruction, except for the case where the `J` instruction is located in the last word of a 256 MB region.

Comment: Ok so you're confirming my hypotesis that if the jump instruction and the destination are in 2 different regions, even if separated by 1 instruction, you can't do the jump?

Comment: _"if the jump instruction and the destination are in 2 different regions, even if separated by 1 instruction, you can't do the jump?"_ You can in the specific case where the jump instruction is located in the last word of a 256 MB region.

Comment: I suppose that's the case because the PC value shifts to PC + 4 in the process of being fetched, so it becomes the first address of the next region?